# Measure of prediction accuracy for discrete time series with zero values

Tags: percentage, prediction, forecasting, measurement, forecast

I make predictions for the on and off time of a machine. This looks like the following picture, where red are the actual values and blue are the forecast values.
[image]

For the forecasts I would like to be able to say by what percentage the forecast differs from the actual values.
Therefore I looked at the MAPE (mean absolute percentage error), but it doesn't work, because I also have zero values in the actual values.

What kind of prediction accuracy measurement would you recommend for time series that look like the ones in the picture?

Comment: Looks more like a classification problem,  and use accuracy or  AUC